# Input from within shell script

Tags: shell

I have a script that calls an application that requires user input, e.g. run app that requires user to type in 'Y' or 'N'.
How can I get the shell script not to ask the user for the input but rather use the value from a predefined variable in the script?

In my case there will be two questions that require input.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pipe in whatever text you'd like on stdin and it will be just the same as having the user type it themselves.  For example to simulating typing "Y" just use:

```
echo "Y" | myapp
```

or using a shell variable:

```
echo $ANSWER | myapp
```

There is also a unix command called "yes" that outputs a continuous stream of "y" for apps that ask lots of questions that you just want to answer in the affirmative.

Comment: In that case, try using the "printf" command rather than echo, and include newlines in the string.  So if you want to answer "Y" then "N" use:  printf "Y\nN\n" | myapp

Comment: Better to make that `printf '%s\n' Y N`. That way you don't need to audit all your values for whether they're valid format strings.

Answer (score 3):

If the app reads from stdin (as opposed to from /dev/tty, as e.g. the `passwd` program does), then multiline input is the perfect candidate for a here-document.

```
#!/bin/sh

the_app [app options here] <<EOF
Yes
No
Maybe
Do it with $SHELL
Quit
EOF
```

As you can see, here-documents even allow parameter substitution. If you don't want this, use `<<'EOF'`.

Answer (score 2):

the expect command for more complicated situations, you system should have it. Haven't used it much myself, but I suspect its what you're looking for.

```
$ man expect
```

http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html

Comment: Dont seem to have 'expect' here - running on HPUX11

Comment: Install it. expect is an invaluable tool.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way: If You want multiple inputs... you put in multiple echo statements as so:

```
 { echo Y; Y; } | sh install.sh >> install.out
```

In the example above... I am feeding two inputs into the install.sh script. Then... at the end, I am piping the script output to a log file to be archived and viewed for later.