# How to fix the issue “Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1” in my shell script phase

Tags: ios, xcode, shell

Building my iOS app using XCode,
I am trying to run a shell script to obfuscate my project code. I got the following error while doing that.

> WARNING: This will wipe all your not committed changes in your
>   repository
>   Press Ctrl-C to Cancel or Enter to proceed.
>
> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It would probably help to see the actual shell script.

Comment: this has nothing to do with iphone, I edited the question. BUT we need xcode version & the actual script

Comment: Based on the warning text, the script awaits user input to proceed. since xcode runs it headless and there is no user input ever, it will be killed eventually

Comment: Post the script.  I suspect it isn't doing what you think.

Comment: https://github.com/Polidea/ios-class-guard

Comment: a script file called obfuscate_project

Answer (score 3):

Based on the warning text, the script awaits user input to proceed. since xcode runs it headless and there is no user input ever, it will be killed eventually

looking at the script I am right:

```
# Just in case
echo "WARNING: This will wipe all your not commited changes in your repository"
echo "Press Ctrl-C to Cancel or Enter to proceed."
read
```

Solution to the issue posted: 
EITHER Remove that code (I would... for a script phase thats not good IMO)
OR fake input to the shell script (see [Input from within shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399734/input-from-within-shell-script))