# Respond to multiple y/n script prompts; shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to automate a chain of commands, one of which requires multiple user inputs of either yes/no. How can I script this so that my script automatically chooses multiple answers?

Example from the command `checkinstall`:

`Do you want me to list them?  [n]:` *(I want to answer no/n here)*

`Should I exclude them from the package? [n]:`  *(I want to answer yes/y here)*

As you can see the `checkinstall` command wants more than 1 input. When I want to just give a command 1 input I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399734/input-from-within-shell-script) method.

Answer (score 2):

Use here document `<<`.

```
checkinstall <<EOF
no
yes
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could script with expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

spawn "./application"

expect "Are you a human?: " { send "yes\r" }
expect "Are you a android :" { send "no\r" }

interact
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [yes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes).

```
yes $'n\ny' | checkinstall
```

Works also, if you call your command more than once.

```
yes $'n\ny' | for n in 1 2 3; do checkinstall; done
```